# For /f error - cannot find the path specified

Tags: windows

I am trying to run the following for files command to delete all *.wer and *.tmp files in multiple "WER" folders.

```
for /f "tokens=1" %a in ('dir c:\users\* /ad /b ') do ( cd C:\Users\%a\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER del /s *.wer *.tmp.*)
```

I can swear this use to work before, but doing it today I get the following error. The system cannot the find the path specified. It's probably just a syntax error, but I cannot see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for some reason.

```
for /f "tokens=1" %a in ('dir c:\users\* /ad /b ') do cd C:\Users\%a\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER & del /s *.wer *.tmp.*
```

CAn't understand why having it in brackets did not work. How strange.

Comment: You missed the `&` before.

Answer (score 0):

This is just `del` telling you that it could not find anything to delete.

Also, by default you don't have access to other users' profile directories.

Furthermore, please don't use `for /f` on the output of `dir`. It's error-prone and unnecessary. You can use the following instead:

```
for /d %U in (C:\Users\*) do (
   pushd C:\Users\%U\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER
   del /s *.wer *.tmp.*
   popd
)
```

Comment: I am actually testing this to another directory, and it still doesn't work. Your command does not work I'm afraid.Syntax incorrect

Comment: Tried the following to a directory I know I've got accesses. `for /f "tokens=1" %a in ('dir c:\temp\* /ad /b ') do ( cd C:\temp\%a\WER del /s *.*)`